# Is Repository pattern a design pattern?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

Is Repository pattern a design pattern ? In the list of design pattern by Gang of four its not there. If its a design pattern then under which category of patterns i.e., creational, stuctural or behavioural does it come. If not then why. Please clear my confusion?

Answer (score 4):

Clasifying patterns can be hard. It's true that the GOF book did add categories of patterns, but most of the time people cannot figure out if something is a **Design Pattern** of **Architectural style** let alone the category of a pattern.

The [Repository pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) was introduces in the book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) which was released after the GOF book.

From it's definition:

> A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers...

we can say that it's a *Structural pattern*.

Sometimes people do use **Repository** to create objects too, so in this case it can also be a *Creational pattern*.

So it depends on how much responsibility has beed given to it, but most of the time we can clasify it as a *Creational pattern*.

As a pattern, the **Repository** has many variations and it's difficult to put it in a category. There are also a lot of discussions on it: what responsibilies it has, how it should be implemented etc.

Not to mentions that people started using **Repositories** with mapping layers for databases that support ACID transactions in combination with [Unif Of Work](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) that managed these transactions and saving changes to the DB.

Nowdays people use MongoDB and [Event Sourcing](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) and add additional methods like **.Save** to it. These methods do provoke a lot of discussion.